# Start and Stop a periodically background Task with Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, task, bots, django-channels

I would like to make a bitcoin notification with Django. If managed to have a working Telegram bot that send the bitcoin stat when I ask him to do so. Now I would like him to send me a message if bitcoin reaches a specific value. There are some tutorials with running python script on server but not with Django. I read some answers and descriptions about django channels but couldn't adapt them to my project.

I would like to send, by telegram, a command about the amount and duration. Django would then start a process with these values and values of the channel I'm sending from in the background. If now, within the duration, the amount is reached, Django sends a message back to my channel. This should also be possible for more than one person.

Is these possible to do with Django out of the box, maybe with decorators, or do I need django-channels or something else?

**Edit 2018-08-10:**
Maybe my code explains a little bit better what I want to do.

```py
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings

from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.decorators.csrf 
import csrf_exempt


class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'telapi/about.html'


bot_token = settings.BOT_TOKEN


def get_url(method):
    return 'https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/{}'.format(bot_token, method)


def process_message(update):
    data = {}
    data['chat_id'] = update['message']['from']['id']
    data['text'] = "I can hear you!"
    r = requests.post(get_url('sendMessage'), data=data)


@csrf_exempt
def process_update(request, r_bot_token):
    ''' Method that is called from telegram-bot'''
    if request.method == 'POST' and r_bot_token == bot_token:
        update = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        if 'message' in update:
            if update['message']['text'] == 'give me news':
                new_bitcoin_price(update)
            else:
                process_message(update)
            return HttpResponse(status=200)


bitconin_api_uri = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/?convert=EUR'
# response = requests.get(bitconin_api_uri)


def get_latest_bitcoin_price():
    response = requests.get(bitconin_api_uri)
    response_json = response.json()
    euro_price = float(response_json['data']['quotes']['EUR']['price'])
    timestamp = int(response_json['metadata']['timestamp'])
    date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return euro_price, date


def new_bitcoin_price(update):
    data = {}
    data['chat_id'] = update['message']['from']['id']
    euro_price, date = get_latest_bitcoin_price()
    data['text'] = "Aktuel ({}) beträgt der Preis {:.2f}€".format(
        date, euro_price)
    r = requests.post(get_url('sendMessage'), data=data)
```

**Edit 2018-08-13:**
I think the solution would be celery-beat and channels. Does anyone know a good tutorial?

Comment: https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue, there are several typical approaches: Celery, Django-Channels, etc.
But you can avoid them all with simple approach: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

I have used django commands in my project to run periodically tasks to rebuild users statistics:

1. Implement yourself application command, for example your application name is `myapp` and you have placed `my_periodic_task.py` in `myapp/management/commands` folder, so you can run your task once by typing `python manage.py my_periodic_task`
2. place beside `manage.py` file new file for example `background.py` with same code:

-

```
import os
from subprocess import call

BASE = os.path.dirname(__file__)
MANAGE_BASE = os.path.join(BASE, 'manage.py')

while True:
    sleep(YOUR_TIMEOUT)
    call(['python', MANAGE_BASE , 'my_periodic_task'])
```

3. Run your server for example: `python background.py & python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I thought of a solution without a script to run in parallel. Maybe I misdescribed myself. It should work more like a query that works dirrerently for each user or (telegram)chat

Comment: Take a look to https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/javascript.html  It is available to run javascript background script for every active user session on browser side and websocker consumer on server side

Answer (score 1):

One of my teammates uses django-celery-beat, that is available at https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat to do this and he gave me some excellent feedback from it. You can schedule the celery tasks using the crontab syntax.

Comment: Hi, your clue is the closest thing to the solution. Now I would also like to link celery-beat to channels. There are not so many instructions for this.

Comment: I can ask for some code and publish it here as soon as I am back at work ... next week.

Comment: @Mactov been a pretty long week I see :D